# Program getting executed indefinetly after comparing with system time

Tags: java

Explanation -
StartTime is being fetched from a table (EX- 2014-07-25 12:00:00)

Startwork() does the insert function

```
do {
    long time = startTime.getTime() + (((59 * 60) + 59) * 1000);
    Date endTime = new Date(time);
    System.out.println("INFO:   Calling startWork(" + startTime + "," + endTime + ")");
    startWork(startTime, endTime);
    startTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000));
    systemHour = new Date(new Date().getYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), new Date().getHours(), 0, 0);
    String stringToUpdateLastProcessedTime = "update meter_thread set last_processed_time='" + sdf.format(startTime) + "' where name='Gateway Park Occupancy' ";
    mysqlStatement.executeUpdate(stringToUpdateLastProcessedTime);
}
while (startTime.getTime() != systemHour.getTime());
System.out.println("INFO:   Switching to live mode");
Thread.sleep(1000 * 55 * 60);
```

The problem I am encountering is that, the program is getting executed for future dates if the starttime fetched from the table is (ex -2014-07-25 12:00:00) and the current system time is (ex-2014-07-25 12:20:00) instead of switching to live mode.

Please help in where I am going wrong.

Comment: Try using > instead of != .

Answer (score 1):

I would change:

```
while(startTime.getTime() != systemHour.getTime())
```

For

```
while(startTime.getTime() > systemHour.getTime())
```

Is rather improbable (almost impossible) that your loop check will match to the millisecond the `startTime` instant.